# How are "premade" lobbies matched against opponents?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am lead to believe that the matchmaking system in League of Legends matches you against opponents based on summoner level. However, in the case where you have a pre-game lobby with players of different summoner levels, how is your lobby matched again opponents? Is it based on *highest* summoner level, *lowest*, *average*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zileas, design director for LoL, explains:

> The system guesses how good you are based on who you beat and who you lose to. It tries to make matches where it thinks you have a 50/50 chance of winning.
>
> It knows pre-made teams are an advantage, so it gives you tougher opponents when you are in a pre-made team. We did fancy math to make the pre-made teams vs solo players matching fair. I even ran it by two math Ph.Ds and they said it made sense!

You can read the full shebang [here](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=12029). Basically, a custom ELO derivative is used to rank players and power the matchmaking system, so that you are paired with similarly ranked teams.

Comment: Despite the post in the above link being 1.75 years old, it is still, to the best of my knowledge, how things work.

Comment: Please refrain from posting answers where the content is entirely behind one link. Links break and may be filtered by companies. Consider adding a summary to your answer.